# When representations of reductive Lie group in a Banach space and in its Garding space have the same length?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a real reductive Lie group (e.g. $G=\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$). Let $\rho$ be a continuous representation of $G$ in a Banach space $V$. Let $V^\infty\subset V$ be the subspace of smooth vectors equipped with the Garding topology. Let $\rho^\infty$ be the natural representation of $G$ in $V^\infty$.

**Under what precise technical conditions the representations $\rho$ and $\rho^\infty$ have the same length?**

As far as I understand this situation is rather typical in the theory.

A reference would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $V^\infty$ with its Fréchet topology. and irreducibility means no closed invariant subspaces except for the trivial ones. Then $V$ is irreducible iff $V^\infty $ is irreducible. In the book Warner, [Harmonic Analysis on semisimple Lie groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-50275-0), Chapter 4, you will find more about this.

Comment: Does it require some admissibility of $V$?

Comment: @makt's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390566/when-representations-of-reductive-lie-group-in-a-banach-space-and-in-its-garding#comment997124_391030) is addressed in [another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/391230).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you need K-admissibility. You can check if it fails in the following example: write the usual Iwasawa for $\operatorname{SL}_2(R)=KAN$, $MAN$ usual parabolic. Fix $ T$ a continuous linear operator in a Banach space without closed invariant subspaces (Enflo's example). Now, it is known that $\operatorname{Ind}_{MAN}^{\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)}(1\otimes e^{T\cdot}\otimes 1)$ is irreducible and it is not admissible. Let me call to your attention Section 11.8 in Wallach Real reductive groups II.

Comment: It seems like it might be a good idea to combine your [two](https://mathoverflow.net/a/391030) answers, rather than to make two separate answers.